# Conversion of doc to docx

Tags: document, conversion

How do I convert doc to docx files without losing the version history and also be able to open the prior versions?

Comment: What is your SharePoint version?

Comment: SharePoint does not have a solution for this. Word Automation Services will create new items, but not overwrite existing items.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the Doc file using Word Automation services (on-prem) or Graph API (online), rename the document from *.doc to *.docx in the document library and add the docx converted file as a new version. This definitely requires a bit of custom code or workflow or manual work...